# Is there a function similar as `np.outer` for vector/matrix "outer" product?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I was wondering if there is a function in `numpy` that acts similarly to `np.outer`, but with a bi-dimensional array and a vector as input parameters. The resould should be a 3-dimensional array.

For example, if I have a matrix `M` and a vector `v`, I would like to have the original matrix `M` stacked `len(v)` times with each "slice" being `M*v[j]` with `j` position parameter.

Is that existing in numpy or should I implement that myself (with possible loss of performance)?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using normal [array broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
M = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [6, 7, 8]])

v = np.arange(4)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3])

Mv = M[:, :, None] * v[None, None, :]
# array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
#         [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#         [ 0,  2,  4,  6]],

#        [[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
#         [ 0,  4,  8, 12],
#         [ 0,  5, 10, 15]],

#        [[ 0,  6, 12, 18],
#         [ 0,  7, 14, 21],
#         [ 0,  8, 16, 24]]])

# you could use np.newaxis in place of None (np.newaxis is just an alias of 
# None). you could also omit the 'None's in the indices into v:
# Mv = M[:, :, None] * v

# check
for jj in xrange(v.shape[0]):
    assert np.all(Mv[:, :, jj] == M * v[jj])
```

Comment: No need for the extra `None, None` indexing in  `v`: `Mv = M[:, :, None] * v`.

Comment: @OliverW. It's a matter of taste - I actually prefer to leave the extra `None`s in, since it makes the broadcasting dimensions more explicit

Comment: If you want it to be more explicit, you could consider replacing `None` by `np.newaxis`. Only those familiar with `numpy` will know they're the same and new folks might be wondering why we index with `None`. But we're agreeing on the same thing here: there is no need for the extra None, even though it could be added. De gustibus et coloribus...

Comment: @OliverW. I just added a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `np.einsum`. In some cases, once you get familiar with it, it results in a more clear syntax (to me):

```
Mv = np.einsum('ij, k->ijk', M, v)
```